# JSON printed to console shows wrong encoding

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, utf-8, cyrillic

I am trying to read Cyrillic characters from some JSON file and then output it to console using **Python 3.4.3 on Windows**. Normal print('Russian smth буквы') works as intended.

But when I print JSON contents it seems to print in Windows-1251 - "СЂСѓСЃСЃРєРёРµ Р±СѓРєРІС‹" (though my console, my JSON file and my .py (with coding comment) are in UTF-8).

I've tried re-encoding it to Win-1251 and setting console to Win-1251, but still no luck.

*My JSON (Encoded in UTF-8):*

```
{
  "русские буквы": "что-то ещё на русском",
  "english letters": "и что-то на великом"
}
```

*My code to load dictionary:*

```
def load_dictionary():
global Dictionary, isFatal
try:
    with open(DictionaryName) as f:
        Dictionary = json.load(f)
except Exception as e:
    logging.critical('Error loading dictionary: ' + str(e))
    isFatal = True
    return
logging.info('Dictionary was loaded successfully')
```

I am trying to output it in 2 ways (both show the same gibberish):

```
print(helper.Dictionary.get('rly'))
print(helper.Dictionary)
```

---

An interesting add-on: I've added the whole Russian alphabet to my JSON file and it seems to **get stuck at "С с" letter**. *(Error loading dictionary: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position X: character maps to )*. If I remove this one letter it shows no exception, but the problem above remains.

Comment: We see how you're loading the JSON, but where and how are you outputting it?

Comment: Added this info, sorry. @deceze

Comment: Probably `open(DictionaryName, encoding="utf8")` helps

Comment: @nauer no, it doesn't. I tried that before asking the question.

Comment: What happens when you open it in binary mode? `with open(DictionaryName, "rb") as f:`

Comment: Binary output:

`b'\n'
b' '
b' '
b'"'
b'r'
b'l'
b'y'
b'"'
b':'
b' '
b'"'
b'\xd1'
b'\x80'
b'\xd1'
b'\x83'
b'\xd1'
b'\x81'
b'\xd1'
b'\x81'
b'\xd0'
b'\xba'
b'\xd0'
b'\xb8'
b'\xd0'
b'\xb9'
b'"'
b'\n'
b'}'
b''`

Used JSON:

`{
  "rly": "русский"
}` @nauer

Comment: Use https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console

Comment: "_But when I print JSON contents_"… If  you print it using `type` command, then you get mojibake `СЂСѓСЃСЃРєРёРµ …` instead of `русские …` under `CHCP 1251` scope. Try `type` under `CHCP 65001` scope. Follow @nauer's advice, use `open(DictionaryName, encoding="utf8")`. BTW, read and follow [mcve]; your question does not satisfy _mcve_ rules.

Comment: @JosefZ Make this and answer and I will accept it as the right one. Thanks a lot for your help, it works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*But when I print JSON contents …*"

If you print it using `type` command, then you get [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) `СЂСѓСЃСЃРєРёРµ …` instead of `русские …` under `CHCP 1251` scope.

Try `type` under [`CHCP 65001` (i.e. `UTF-8`)](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) scope.

Follow [nauer's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755662/json-printed-to-console-shows-wrong-encoding?noredirect=1#comment66807809_39755662), use `open(DictionaryName, encoding="utf8")`.

**Example** (`39755662.json` is saved with `UTF-8` encoding):

```
==> chcp 866
Active code page: 866

==> type 39755662.json
{
  "╤А╤Г╤Б╤Б╨║╨╕╨╡ ╨▒╤Г╨║╨▓╤Л": "╤З╤В╨╛-╤В╨╛ ╨╡╤Й╤С ╨╜╨░ ╤А╤Г╤Б╤Б╨║╨╛╨╝",
  "rly": "╤А╤Г╤Б╤Б╨║╨╕╨╣"
}

==> chcp 1251
Active code page: 1251

==> type 39755662.json
{
  "СЂСѓСЃСЃРєРёРµ Р±СѓРєРІС‹": "С‡С‚Рѕ-С‚Рѕ РµС‰С‘ РЅР° СЂСѓСЃСЃРєРѕРј",
  "rly": "СЂСѓСЃСЃРєРёР№"
}

==> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

==> type 39755662.json
{
  "русские буквы": "что-то ещё на русском",
  "rly": "русский"
}

==>
```